# Which one of the following statements are true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Which one of the following statements are true?

(a) If $f(z)$ is a power series that converges on $\mathbb D$. $F(1/2)=i$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $z\in \mathbb D$. the $f(\pi/4)=i.$

(b)If $f(z)$ is a power series that converges on $\mathbb C$.  $|f(z)|\leq |f(i)|$ for $z\in  \overline{\mathbb D}$. then $f$ is a constant function.

(c)If $f(z)$ is a power series that converges on $\mathbb D$.  $|f(z)|\ge|f(i/2)|$ for $z\in  {\mathbb D}$. then $f$ is a constant function.

**My attempt:-**
(a) I apply shwarz-Pick lemma. I used the pseudo hyperbolic metric relation here, $\frac{|f(z)-f(w)|}{1-f(z)\overline{f(w)}} \leq \frac{z-w}{1-z\overline{w}}$. Applying $z=1/2$ and $z=\pi/4$. I got Left hand side inequality indeterminate form and right side a constant. So, This is false.

(b) I applied, Lioviole's theorem. hence, $f$ is constant.

(c) I have no idea for third one.
Is my ideas correct? Please give some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is true: $f$ is constant because of the maximum modulus principle. The Schwarz-Pick lemma requires that $|f(z) | < 1$ for all $z \in \Bbb D$, so that cannot be used here.

(b) is false, $f(z) = z$ is a counterexample. You cannot apply Liouville's theorem here because $f$ is only bounded in the unit disk, not on all of $\Bbb C$.

(c) is false, $f(z) = z-i/2$ is a counterexample, or any non-constant function with $f(i/2) = 0$. (If you had $|f(z)|\ge|f(i/2)| > 0$ then you could apply the maximum modulus principle to $1/f$ and conclude that $f$ is constant.)